# Resolving a name collision in 3rd party gem code

Tags: ruby, rubygems

My project depends on [Sunspot](http://rubygems.org/gems/sunspot), which in turn depends on [progress_bar](http://rubygems.org/gems/progress_bar). progress_bar defines a class (outside of any module/namespace) called `ProgressBar`.

My test code depends on [minitest-reporters](http://rubygems.org/gems/minitest-reporters), which in turn depends on [ruby-progressbar](http://rubygems.org/gems/ruby-progressbar). ruby-progressbar defines a class (also outside of any module/namespace) called `ProgressBar`.

Being new to Ruby, it took me an embarassing amount of time to track down the fact that the two `ProgressBar` classes were conflicting. I know how to namespace my own code to prevent such problems, but is there any way to resolve such a collision in 3rd party code?

**Update**:

The owner of minitest-reporters very kindly replaced his usage of the (apparently abandoned) ProgressBar with yet another progress library, [PowerBar](http://rubygems.org/gems/powerbar). So this addressed my problem. But guess what- PowerBar also pollutes the global namespace! This just seems pathological in Ruby...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- If it's in your own code (not applicable in this particular case): **namespace your friggin constants!**
- If it's in someone else's code: file a bug telling them to **namespace their friggin constants!** … and wait for them to release a new version …

There's really not more you can do.

Comment: Fork PowerBar, make it **namespace its frigging constants**, submit a pull request.

Until they merge your PR you can use your forked version in Gemfile.

Comment: This isn't always an option, and it doesn't really answer the question.

Answer (score 10):

If you're faced with

```
# alice_bad_code.rb

class ProgressBar
  def initialize
    puts "Alice bad code progress bar created"
  end
end

class AliceBadCode
  def initialize
    @progress_bar = ProgressBar.new
  end
end
```

and

```
# bob_bad_code.rb

class ProgressBar
  def initialize
    puts "Bob bad code progress bar created"
  end
end

class BobBadCode
  def initialize
    @progress_bar = ProgressBar.new
  end
end
```

Then I'd try something like

```
require "alice_bad_code"
class AliceBadCode
  ProgressBar = ::ProgressBar
end
Object.send(:remove_const, "ProgressBar")

require "bob_bad_code"
class BobBadCode
  ProgressBar = ::ProgressBar
end
Object.send(:remove_const, "ProgressBar") # Just in case
```

Welcome to Ruby metaprogramming!

However, the best way to monkey patch a third-party library is not to monkey patch it at all, and file a bug report as per Jorg W Mittag's answer.